# How do you execute SQL from within a bash script?

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, plsql, sqlplus

I have some SQL scripts that I'm trying to automate. In the past I have used SQL*Plus, and called the sqlplus binary manually, from a bash script.

However, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to connect to the DB, and call the script from inside of the bash script... so that I can insert `date` and make the queries run relative to a certain number of days in the past.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm slightly confused.  You should be able to call sqlplus from within the bash script.  This may be what you were doing with your first statement

Try Executing the following within your bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash          
echo Start Executing SQL commands
sqlplus <user>/<password> @file-with-sql-1.sql
sqlplus <user>/<password> @file-with-sql-2.sql
```

If you want to be able to pass data into your scripts you can do it via SQLPlus by passing arguments into the script:

Contents of **file-with-sql-1.sql**

```
 select * from users where username='&1';
```

Then change the bash script to call sqlplus passing in the value

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_USER=bob
sqlplus <user>/<password> @file-with-sql-1.sql $MY_USER
```

Comment: any idea how to the same with postgres?

Answer (score 9):

You can also use a "here document" to do the same thing:

```
VARIABLE=SOMEVALUE

sqlplus connectioninfo << HERE
start file1.sql
start file2.sql $VARIABLE
quit
HERE
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple way of running MySQL queries in the bash shell

```
mysql -u [database_username] -p [database_password] -D [database_name] -e "SELECT * FROM [table_name]"
```

Comment: This is not oracle.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can pipe SQL query to sqlplus. It works for mysql:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM table" | mysql --user=username database
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the jdbcsql project on Sourceforge.

On *nix systems, this will create a csv stream of results to standard out:

```
java -Djava.security.egd=file///dev/urandom -jar jdbcsql.jar -d oracledb_SID -h $host -p 1521 -U some_username -m oracle -P "$PW" -f excel -s "," "$1"
```

Note that adding the `-Djava.security.egd=file///dev/urandom` increases performance greatly

Windows commands are similar: see http://jdbcsql.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to install `sqlplus` on your server/machine then the following command-line tool can be your friend. It is a simple Java application, only Java 8 that you need in order to you can execute this tool.

The tool can be used to run any SQL from the Linux bash or Windows command line.

**Example:**

```
java -jar sql-runner-0.2.0-with-dependencies.jar \
     -j jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle-db:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain \
     -U "SYS as SYSDBA" \
     -P Oradoc_db1 \
      "select 1 from dual"
```

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/zappee/sql-runner/tree/0.2.1).

You can download the binary file from [here](https://github.com/zappee/sql-runner/tree/0.2.1/bin).

Answer (score -5):

As Bash doesn't have built in sql database connectivity... you will need to use some sort of third party tool.

Comment: sqlplus _is_ that "third party tool"