# How do I create a flat file with values fetched from a database in UNIX?

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

How do I create a flat file with values fetched from a database ( using select ) in UNIX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQLPlus, use the [SPOOL directive](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/spool.html) to output script output to a file.  This [SO question details how to get a CSV file via SQLPlus/SPOOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus), for example.

```
SPOOL your_file.txt

    SELECT 1, 'test' 
      FROM DUAL

SPOOL OFF
```

Related:

- [Oracle/PLSQL: Execute an SQL script file in SQLPlus](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call `sqlplus` from within a shell script, and pipe the results to a flat file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467846/how-do-you-execute-sql-from-within-a-bash-script/1467893#1467893) for details.

Answer (score 1):

For variables passed to a shell script try a here document:

```
#!/bin/ksh
var=$(printf "'%s'" `date +%b-%d-%Y`)
sqlplus -s me/mtpasswd@mydbname <<! 
   set pages 55
   spool outfile.lis
   select * from mytable where sales_date= $var ;
   spool off
!
```

This uses todays date.  The flat file is outfile.lis