# SQL query within BASH

Tags: sql, oracle, bash

I have a BASH script like the below:

```
#!/bin/bash

email_template="Subject: Subject
From: example@example.com
To: %s

%s
%s
%s
"

cat test.out | while read num email limit orders; do
    echo "Sending mail to '$email'"
    printf "$email_template" "$email" "$num" "$limit" "$orders" |
    sendmail -oi -t
done
```

Also there is a `.sql` file with a SQL query contained within that does a SPOOL to `test.out` with results. How can I make it so that this is all done within the BASH script above (SQL in BASH script, no `cat` etc.)?

Comment: Try the following: 
sqlplus <user>/<password> @file-with-sql-1.sql
Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467846/how-do-you-execute-sql-from-within-a-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the .sql file it is more difficult to say but here are some possibilities:

Add the .sql inline and store it in a bash variable:

```
mysqlquery="select * from foo;
selct * from baz;
select * from bar;"

echo "${mysqlquery}"|mysql
```

If you keep the .sql file separate then you can do something like:

```
mysql < /path/sqlFile.sql
```