# how to connect to a oracle db in bash script?

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, sqlplus

I have a script that needs to connect to oracle db hosted on a different server .I am able to connect to this oracle db using sqldeveloper.But i am not able to configured it in my bash script .
SQLDEVELOPER 4.0 is the tool that i use to connect through gui .How can i use this in my script .Is there any other way to do it ?Do i need any other software (sqlplus)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you execute SQL from within a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467846/how-do-you-execute-sql-from-within-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

try using following once:

```
sqlplus db_user_name/password_for_user@DB_schema < Input_file.sql > Output
```

Answer (score 0):

You need sqlplus to achieve what you're trying to do. The syntax of the command you need to put in you shell script should be like:

```
sqlplus 'USER/PASSWORD@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DB_HOST)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE_NAME_YOU_USE_IN_SQLDEVELOPER)))'
```

Answer (score 0):

On *nix systems, this will create a csv stream of results to standard out:

```
java -Djava.security.egd=file///dev/urandom -jar jdbcsql.jar -d oracledb_SID -h $host -p 1521 -U some_username -m oracle -P "$PW" -f excel -s "," "$1"
```

Note that adding the `-Djava.security.egd=file///dev/urandom` increases performance greatly

Windows commands are similar: see http://jdbcsql.sourceforge.net/